# How do I use nested namespaces for custom controls?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, namespaces, windows-forms-designer

I have defined a user control, ExpressionControl, under the namespace:

```
TriggerEditor.UserControls
```

I have a form, "IfEditor", under the namespace:

```
TriggerEditor.Forms
```

When I add an instance of my control to the form (naming it expCondition), the following code is generated in the Designer to create the control:

```
this.expCondition = new TriggerEditor.UserControls.ExpressionControl();
```

This results in the following compilation error:

```
The type name 'UserControls' does not exist in the type 'TriggerEditor.Forms.TriggerEditor'
```

I don't understand why it is looking in "TriggerEditor.Forms.TriggerEditor"; that's not what the code says. Now, I can resolve this error manually by modifying the line, removing the "TriggerEditor." that preceeds "TriggerControls", as such:

```
this.expCondition = new UserControls.ExpressionControl();
```

This satisfies the compiler, however I obviously don't want to do this every time I add an instance of my ExpressionControl to a form. How do I avoid this situation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you might have a `TriggerEditor` class within the `TriggerEditor.Forms` namespace; is this the case?

If so, because the `TriggerEditor` class is within your current namespace, you are "closer" to this class, and therefore it is looking for a subclass.

Comment: You are right. I'd been splitting my projects and renaming classes and didn't even notice I had a naming conflict on my hands.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using the same name for a class and a namespace!?

Apparently, in the namespace `TriggerEditor.Forms`, you have a class named `TriggerEditor` in the same namespace as your IfEditor class.

So, when looking for `TriggerEditor.UserControls.ExpressionControl`, the compiler looks in the `TriggerEditor` class (which is in the same namespace, so closer) instead of the `TriggerEditor` namespace...

Normally, to avoid that, you would use a [namespace alias qualifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c3ay4x3d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx), but being in a Designer generated class, you can't really control that.

Comment: Your answer is correct as well. Unfortunately I can't accept more than one. Upvoted, though, and thank you.